# How to programmatically play an Audio object?

Tags: sound

A [`Sound`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sound.html) object can be programmatically played using [`EmitSound`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmitSound.html).  Example:

```
snd = ExampleData[{"Sound", "AltoFlute"}];

Button["Play!", EmitSound[snd]]
```

What about an [`Audio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Audio.html) object?

Comment: As a version 10 user I don't get it: why is there both `Audio` and `Sound` in v11?  Is this a case of *oops, we didn't plan well with `Sound` so let's try again with `Audio`* or is there a completely different application that requires a different container?

Comment: `Audio[]` can do out-of-core stuff, e.g. `Audio["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/bach.mp3"]`, Why `Sound[]` was not modified to have that ability as well, I dunno...

Comment: @MrW `Audio` is supposed to be more like `Image`.  It is highly optimized and atomic.  `Sound` can't really be made atomic as it is meant to hold either wave or midi data and it is meant to be dissected by users. More importantly, Audio supports out-of-core processing.  We can have `Audio[File[...]]` which won't load all the data into memory.  Applying a filter to it produces another file-backed object.

Comment: @MrW However, in my tests Audio filters are much slower than the equivalent filter in the open source Audacity, so I think it has a long way to go.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have a same confusion with @Mr.Wizard ,Why the W.R. make a new `Audio` but not refine the old `Sound`?And it's seem the *Mathematica* process the `Audio` file which have a same size with `Image` is lower efficiency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following resulted from a lot of spelunking and reading the code of `` Audio`Play ``.

```
au = ExampleData[{"Audio", "Bird"}];

Audio`Internals`Execute[
 Audio`Internals`GetAudioManager[
  Audio`AudioInformation[au, "AudioID"]],
 "Play"
 ]
```

`` Audio`Play `` does the same thing except it gets the `"AudioID"` in a different way which appears to fail.

There are many other commands that can be executed, e.g. `"Stop"`, `"Pause"`, etc.  See the definition of `` Audio`Internals`Execute ``.

If the audio object is being displayed in the notebook, the seekbar will start moving on playback.

**Warning:** This is undocumented functionality. I was doing spelunking in M11.0.1 and `Audio` was introduced in 11.0.0.  I expect that the `Audio` stuff is still under heavy development.  I won't be surprised at all if the above stops working in the next version of *Mathematica*.

Comment: You mean ``Audio`Play`` work?

Comment: @yode No it won't work because insetad of ``Audio`AudioInformation[au, "AudioID"]`` it does `"AudioID" /. Options[au]`, which fails.

Comment: @Szabolcs If I start it playing this way is there a way to get the current time index dynamically as it plays? I tried using ``Audio`Internals`Execute[
 Audio`Internals`GetAudioManager[id], "GetDataPosition"]`` but no luck.

Comment: @M.R. I don't know.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `` Sound`AudioToSound[] `` to convert the `Audio[]` object to a `Sound[]` object that can then be passed to `EmitSound[]`:

```
ExampleData[{"Audio", "Bird"}] // Sound`AudioToSound // EmitSound
```

Of course, this is only recommended for modestly-sized `Audio[]` objects.